# How can I save and read AVAudioRecordings on sqlite?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, avaudiorecorder

I am working on an app that requires me to save audio recordings in the database and retrieve them later. However, while I'm somewhat aware of how to use sqlite, I'm not sure if I'm using the right method when it comes to saving audio recordings, as I have a hard time getting it to work. The current code I'm using to save recordings is listed below and I would appreciate any feedback I receive regarding my code.

```
    self.renameString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,self.soundName.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.renameString);

        self.soundFileURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.renameString];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.soundFileURL2);

        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *renameError;

        [fm moveItemAtURL:self.soundFileURL toURL:self.soundFileURL2 error:&renameError];

        [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

        self.soundName.text = @"";

        BOOL checkQuery;
        NSData *blob;
        blob = self.voiceData;

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *insert = [self.renameString UTF8String];
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(soundDB, insert, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK) {
                checkQuery=NO;  
            }
            else {
                sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [blob bytes], [blob length], NULL);

                if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement)) {
                    checkQuery=NO;
                }
                else {
                    // NSLog(@"Query Working nicely");
                    checkQuery=YES; 

                    sqlite3_reset(statement);
                }
            }
        //}
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);    
        sqlite3_close(soundDB);
```

I'm also aware that in order to retrieve the saved file, you have to declare a new NSData variable and assign the reading to that variable. Afterwards, you have to extract the NSData and put it in another variable itself. The problem is, while I'm aware of how to extract NSString and UIImage data, I'm not sure about the rules for extracting AVAudioRecorder data. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks.